# Finding array element greater than all previous

Tags: arrays

Q I've been trying to solve.
Given an array : 1 2 2 4 4 6 5 4 5 7 8 9 11 13
Find the first element that is greater than all previous elements and smaller than all elements ahead.
My thinking was to sort the array and then find the first element that had not changed its original position in the array.
What do you think? Anyone has a better approach ?

**Is there a way to do it in less than `O(N^2)` ?**

thanks

Comment: Your approach is the best I can think of for now.. Go with it, it's O(n) - The best you can get. (Edit: It's not O(n) :))

Comment: I'm not sure if your approach would work. Because let's say you have the array `[5, 7, 7, 2]`, it's possible that the second 7 in the array does not move during the sort, but it does not fulfit the condition,

Comment: @MarounMaroun: O(n) for sorting?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun, how can you sort array with O(n)?

Comment: Oops.. my bad, sorry.

Comment: @zouZou: but he is getting the first element of all not moving elements

Comment: @ZouZou I guess that in this case the program will return "no such element"..

Comment: Little clarification: Given an array like `[5,6,7,0,1]`, the unsorted answer would be 6. However if you sorted it the answer would be 1. What is the correct answer here? Also what is all the talk about performance, you mention "better method" however the argument could be made that just because its slightly faster doesnt make it better code. Clarity does account for something.

Comment: @lakshman And the first not moving element would be the second 7 if the sort behaves like I describe, and thus an invalid answer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun For that it requires that you have to perform a check before. The solution "sort it and then check the first not moving position" is not working.

Comment: -1 due to Lack of clarity in the question itself.

Comment: @Braj The poster does ask "Anyone has a better approach?", which your answer technically doesn't fulfill. I think it's pretty clear that if the poster described a `O(n lg n)` algorithm a `O(N^2)` one isn't going to work for that question.

Comment: @user3580294 better approach doesn't mean about the complexity always. there are other aspects to be considered in OOP programming.

Comment: The complexity `O(N^2)` was added later. And @Braj posted a clearer way for solving the problem IMO than the sorting. His code could have helped the questioner to come up with something better.

Comment: @Braj Except that this seems to be more algorithm-based than OOP-related. When dealing with algorithms complexity does play a decently large role in determining "better" or not

Comment: @user3580294 I got it. Just finish it now

Answer (score 7):

1. Sweep from left to right, tracking current maximum. Mark any element that is the current maximum.
2. Sweep from right to left, tracking current minimum. Also track the current leftmost marked element that is also the current minimum.

(With thanks to @Konstantinos for the suggested optimisations in comments below.)

Step 1 finds all elements that satisfy the first criterion, similarly for Step 2. The whole thing is O(n) in time and space.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Oli's solution:

```
public static void getElement(int[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    boolean[] maxis = new boolean[n];
    //compute max
    int max = array[0];
    maxis[0] = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
            maxis[i] = true;
        }
    }
    //initialize requestedNumber, if we get -1 as a reply there is no solution
    int requestedPos = -1;
    int requestedNumber = 0;


    int min = array[n-1];
    if (maxis[n-1]) {
        requestedPos = n-1;
        requestedNumber = min;
    }

    //compute min
    //keep track of current requestedNumber
    for (int i = n - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
            if (maxis[i]) {
                requestedPos = i;
                requestedNumber = min;
            }
        }
    }


    System.out.println(requestedPos);
    System.out.println(requestedNumber);
}
```

Comment: This is cool, but it's generally not a great idea to give complete code answers to homework questions.

Comment: yes that's true, almost forgot it was for a homework, due to the run to prove there exist an O(n) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an even faster approach without requiring additional arrays or markings.

We just need one full table scan and nothing more, so it's obviously O(n):

```
public static void getFirstMinMaxElement(int[] array) {
    //compute max
    int max = array[0];
    int requestedPos = 0; //position
    int requestedNumber = max; //current
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
            //only assign a new requested value if there isn't any
            if (requestedPos == -1) {
                requestedPos = i;
                requestedNumber = max;
            }
        }
        //delete current requestedNumber when you find a smaller one
        //use < instead of <= if you don't care about equal elements 
        else if (array[i] <= requestedNumber) {
            requestedPos = -1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(requestedPos); //if -1, then there is no solution
    System.out.println(requestedNumber);
}
```